The OPC UA server is only accessible via localhost
A server written with open62541, why is it only accessible via localhost?
I tried adding serverurls like this
UA_String serverUrls[2];
size_t serverUrlsSize = 0;

UA_String_clear(config.serverUrls);

serverUrls[serverUrlsSize] = UA_STRING("opc.tcp://:48440");
serverUrlsSize++;
serverUrls[serverUrlsSize] = UA_STRING("opc.tcp://192.9.200.93:48440");
serverUrlsSize++;

retval = UA_Array_copy(serverUrls, serverUrlsSize,
        (void**)&config.serverUrls, &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_STRING]);
if (retval != UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD)
{
    return retval;
}
config.serverUrlsSize = serverUrlsSize;

But nothing helped, so do I still need an lds server to access from outside?

I do not know what the problem was, I converted the project from cmake to a regular visual studio project, it asked for an additional arch/win32/ua_architecture header.h and everything worked... It's unclear why cmake didn't ask him...
